# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not HTTPResponse

Tags: python, api

The purpose of this script is to connect to an API endpoint that provides a .CSV file. I'm not trying to manipulate the data or do anything with the information other than grab it from the endpoint and then save the file to a local directory

I've tested the endpoint and can get a 200 HTTP response from it, but I can not open the file or save it. I continue to get a typeerror response for the last line of the code.

```py
import urllib.request as urllib2
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import csv

url = "Https://API_LINK/Details/full_csv"
request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.add_header('header_details', 'Token token="token_details"')
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
with open(response,'w', newline='') as f:
```

I expected to be able to define the opened file as 'f', then pass 'f' to csv.reader() and then view rows from the file. What do I do to pass the info as bytes and not as just an httpResponse?

Comment: Why are you importing `requests` but only using `urllib2`?

Comment: I was having trouble with the urllib package at first. Should I adjust the packages?

Comment: Well, don't import a package you're not using. And I've generally seen it suggested that `requests` is better than `urllib2`, so you might consider using that instead.

Comment: sorry - i have a part of the script that I didn't post that is to send the request through my company's proxy. That's why I have urllib2. I see now how that could be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html

Calling `.read()` on the response will return the fetched text from the page.

Comment: I added response.read() to the last line and removed the "with" statement. The script executed successfully but there was no output available for me to read.